# How do I decrypt Cliams Identification Encoding:

Tags: 2013, authentication, distributedcache, app-fabric

I recenlty encountered exception in Distributed Cache services, When i looked at the logs i found out certain user account had timed out while trying to access App fabric services.

In Sharepoint logs File say s: Token Cache: Failed to get token from distributed cache for '0).w|s-1-5-21-1569013132-2106423733-3135404513-303780'.

How do i decrypt Encoded Claims Identifier to find out what account was affected?

What does this mean: 0).w|s-1-5-21-1569013132-2106423733-3135404513-303780

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is claims form of user info stored in SharePoint .w means that it's windows account and after the | character is either login name or SID. SID is typically used for groups. You can try to use PowerShell to translate it to something meaningful:

```
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("s-1-5-21-1569013132-2106423733-3135404513-303780")
$objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$objUser.Value
```

Comment: Where am i running this powershell code, i am a sharepoint admin, but i dont have access to AD?

Comment: You don't need any special permissions to AD. Resolving SID is common operation.